# COMO ELIMINAR ERROR net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET en REACT - HELP ME PLEASE

Tags: reactjs, express, multer

Estimados amigos de la gran familia stackoverflow tengo un proyecto muy simple de prueba que envia imagenes a mi backend en express, multer me las guarda en una carpeta y mi backend regresa la informacion de todas mis imagenes almacenanas a mi frontend imprimiendo esta informacion en la consola de mi navegador chrome. Cuando envio 9 imagenes todo perfecto sin errores, pero cuando envio 10 o mas imagenes obtengo el error:

POST http://localhost:3001/enviarImagenes/post net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Les envio el codigo:

APP.JS:

```
import './App.css';
import ListaUsuarios from './componentes/ListaUsuarios'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
       <ListaUsuarios/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ListaUsuarios:

```
import React from "react"
import axios from "axios"
function ListaUsuarios(){

   const  enviar = async(e) =>{
       e.preventDefault()
       const formData  = new FormData(document.getElementById('form')) 
       console.log(formData.get('input'))  
       formData.append('idusuario','LUIS'); 

       await axios.post('http://localhost:3001/enviarImagenes/post',formData)
       .then((response)=>{
            const data = response.data
            console.log("Mi backend me envia esto:")
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
           console.log(error)
        })
   }
   return(     
    <div>Soy la lista
       <form className="form" id="form" onSubmit={enviar}>
          <input className="input"  type="file" id="input" name="input" multiple></input>
          <button type="submit">ENVIAR</button>
       </form>
    </div>
   )
}
export default ListaUsuarios
```

SERVER.JS

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

app.use(require('./routes'))


app.listen('3001',()=>{
  console.log("Servidor corriendo...")
})
```

ROUTES:

```
const { errorMonitor } = require("events")
const express = require("express")
const route = express.Router()
const multer =require("multer")
const path = require('path')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');

const diskstorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: path.join(__dirname, '/assets/static/img'),
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
       // cb(null, Date.now() + '-monkeywit-' + file.originalname)
       cb(null, uuidv4() + path.extname(file.originalname).toLocaleLowerCase())  //otra forma de darle nombre a una imagen con 'uuid'
       //cb(null, (file.originalname).replace(' ', '_').toLocaleLowerCase()) 
    }
  })
  
  const fileUpload = multer({
    storage: diskstorage
  }).array('input')

route.post('/enviarImagenes/post',fileUpload, (req,res)=>{   
    // res.send(req)
    console.log("Usuario: "+req.body.idusuario)
    console.log(req.files)
    res.send(req.files)

})

module.exports  = route
```

MI ESTRUCTURA DE CARPETAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE SE ME PRESENTA CUANDO SELECCIONO 10 O MAS IMAGENES:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar a descifrar este misterio. Gracias de antemano.